# Spring Kafka With TCP Port As Producer

Tags: java, spring, tcp, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to Kafka and Streaming so bear with me.

I have installed and started both zookeeper and Kafka successfully. Created a simple topic and started console consumer that listen and display in console what is being sent to that topic.
Producer currently sends info as a result of endpoint call.

I have a device which will be send `NMEA` format data to a TCP port.
How can i expose a TCP port as a Kafka Producer?

If anyone needs any extra info to help, dont hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write an application that listens to the TCP port, decodes the data into the format you want it, and than hand it over to a `KafkaProducer` to write it into the topic.